# Declaring bitmap values in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, bit-manipulation, uint8t

Basic bit manipulation question. How can I declare a **uint8_t** bitmap value in **Objective-C**?

e.g. **value:** "00000001"

Is it as simple as:

```
uint8_t value = 00000001
```

or does it need to have some **hexadecimal prefix**?

```
uint8_t valuePrefix = 0x00000001
```

Comment: `0x` is for byte representation, not `bit`. For instance, try with `0x01000001` and check the value, it shouldn't be the one that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "bitmap", I assume you're talking about binary representations. If you're specifying a binary number, you use the `0b` prefix:

```
uint8_t value = 0b00000100;  // 4
```

Or, if there's only one bit on, we often use bitwise shift operator:

```
uint8_t value = 1 << 2;      // 4
```